# Projection of ContourPlot3D

Tags: plotting

Suppose I have the following `ContourPlot3D`:

```
ContourPlot3D[
p1 p2^6 (C p1 - (-1 + C) p2)^3 ((-1 + C) p1 - C p2)^2 
== 
(-1 + p1) (-1 + p2)^6 (-1 + C p1 - (-1 + C) p2)^3 (1 + (-1 + C) p1 - C p2)^2,
{p1, 0, 0.3}, {p2, 0.5, 1}, {C, 0, 1}, 
 Lighting -> ({"Directional", White, #} & /@ Tuples[{-1, 1}, 3]), 
 Mesh -> None, ContourStyle -> {Directive[Red, Opacity[0.5]]}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(p\), \(1\)]\)", 
 "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(p\), \(2\)]\)", "C"}]
```

which looks like:

[image]

My question is: how to project this transparent red surface onto the $p_1,p_2$ plane and then convert the projection to a standard 2d plot (like what we will get by using `Plot[]`)

**Additional requirement**: It would be nice if the resulting 2D plot is clean, because I may need to plot other curves on top of the 2D plot.

Comment: `RegionPlot[]`?

Comment: I think `RegionPlot[]` works only for flat plane.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First let's save the plot in `cp`:

```
cp = ContourPlot3D[
  p1 p2^6 (c0 p1 - (-1 + c0) p2)^3 ((-1 + c0) p1 - c0 p2)^2 ==
   (-1 + p1) (-1 + p2)^6 (-1 + p1 - (-1 + c0) p2)^3 (1 + (-1 + c0) p1 - c0 p2)^2,
  {p1, 0, 0.3}, {p2, 0.5, 1}, {c0, 0, 1},
  Lighting -> ({"Directional", White, #} & /@ Tuples[{-1, 1}, 3]), 
  Mesh -> None, ContourStyle -> {Directive[Red, Opacity[0.5]]}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(p\), \(1\)]\)", 
    "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(p\), \(2\)]\)", "C"}];
```

[By the way, you should avoid using capital `C`, which is used by *Mathematica* for constant parameters.]

### The easy way

Project the coordinates of the polygons in `cp` onto the `p1`/`p2` plane:

```
Graphics[
  Cases[cp, GraphicsComplex[pts_, g_, rest___] :>
   GraphicsComplex[
     Most /@ pts,  (* the first two coordinates are p1, p2 *)
     {Directive[Lighter[Red, 0.5]], Cases[g, _Polygon, Infinity]}
    ],
   Infinity],
  Method -> {"TransparentPolygonMesh" -> True}]
```

[image: Envelope]
[image: Envelope with axes]

I replaced the semi-opacity with a semi-light red.  This should be fine if you keep the graphics in the background.  Otherwise, it's harder.

*Graphics styling.*
To get axes on the graph and other features, add `Axes -> True` and [other options](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/GraphicsOptionsAndStyling.html):

```
Graphics[
  Cases[cp, GraphicsComplex[pts_, g_, rest___] :>
   GraphicsComplex[
     Most /@ pts,  (* the first two coordinates are p1, p2 *)
     {Directive[Lighter[Red, 0.5]], Cases[g, _Polygon, Infinity]}
    ],
   Infinity],
  Method -> {"TransparentPolygonMesh" -> True},
  Axes -> True]
```

(See above.)  Others to consider are [`AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/AxesOrigin.html), using [`Frame -> True`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Frame.html) instead of `Axes`, and setting the ratio height/width with [`AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/AspectRatio.html).

### Edit - The hard way -- Envelopes

First, call the equation `eqn` and change `C` to `c0`:

```
eqn = (p1 p2^6 (C p1 - (-1 + C) p2)^3 ((-1 + C) p1 - C p2)^2 ==
    (-1 + p1) (-1 + p2)^6 (-1 + C p1 - (-1 + C) p2)^3 (1 + (-1 + C) p1 - C p2)^2) /. C -> c0
```

> ```
> p1 p2^6 (c0 p1 - (-1 + c0) p2)^3 ((-1 + c0) p1 - c0 p2)^2 ==
>  (-1 + p1) (-1 + p2)^6 (-1 + c0 p1 - (-1 + c0) p2)^3 (1 + (-1 + c0) p1 - c0 p2)^2
> ```

The boundaries of the projection will be either the edges of the 3D plot or the envelope of the surface.  The edges of the 3D graph are where `c` is `0` or `1`.  There are many solutions which we and we have to extract the ones corresponding to the plot.  Luckily the only ones in the plot region are the boundaries and they can be written in the form `p2 = func[p1]`; hence, the boundaries can picked out by inspecting the value of `p2` at some intermediate value of `p1`, say `p1 = 0.15`.

```
sols = Extract[#, Position[p2 /. # /. p1 -> 0.15, p_Real /; 0.5 <= p <= 1]] &@
  Solve[eqn && (0 == c0 || c0 == 1), {c0, p2}]
```

> ```
> {{c0 -> 1, p2 -> (-1 + p1 + Sqrt[p1 - p1^2])/(-1 + 2 p1)},
>  {c0 -> 0, p2 -> 1 - p1 ...omitted...}}
> ```

Here we have to set up the differential equation for the envelope, which will be the points on the surface where the partial derivative with respect to `c0` is zero (`envelope == 0`); the condition "on the surface" is modeled by the integral curve being orthogonal to the gradient (`surface == 0`).  One of the boundary values of the differential equation is `{p1, p2, c0} == {0, 1, 0.}` (I've change the value of `c0` three times because I've been fooled by the *Mathematica* output, the numerics being so tricky). The DE is degenerate there, so we have to find a good initial point for `NDSolve`.  As with `sols` there are many solutions and we have to extract the initial point we want.  There is only one envelope line in the plot region, so finding it presents no trouble.  The solutions found will be of the form `p2 = fp2[p1]`, `c0 = fc0[p1]`, where `fp2`, `fc0` will be the `InterpolatingFunction` returned by `NDSolve`.

```
fnsrule = Thread[{p2, c0} -> {fp2[p1], fc0[p1]}];
envelope = D[Subtract @@ eqn, {c0}] /. fnsrule;
surface = (D[Subtract @@ eqn, {{p1, p2, c0}}] /. fnsrule) . {1, fp2'[p1], fc0'[p1]};
initsol = NSolve[D[Subtract @@ eqn, {c0}] == 0 && eqn == 0 /. p1 -> 1/100, {p2, c0}];
initpt = First @ Extract[initsol, 
   Position[{p2, c0} /. initsol, {p_Real, c_Real} /; 0.5 <= p <= 1 && 0 <= c <= 1]]
```

> ```
> {p2 -> 0.751159, c0 -> 0.267272}
> ```

Expect warning messages.  The choice of `p1 -> 1/100` was through trial and error.  (It's far enough away from `p1 == 0` to stay out of serious trouble and give a good solution.  Getting much closer tended to call for increasing `WorkingPrecision`, but increasing `WorkingPrecision` tended to cause the kernel to crash.)  As you can see below, the DE can be solved for almost all the requested domain.

```
bdy = NDSolve[{envelope == 0, surface == 0,
        fp2[0.01] == p2 /. initpt, fc0[0.01] == c0 /. initpt},
       {fp2, fc0}, {p1, 0, 0.3}]
```

> ```
> {{fp2 -> InterpolatingFunction[{{1.91025*10^-9, 0.3}}, <>],
>   fc0 -> InterpolatingFunction[{{1.91025*10^-9, 0.3}}, <>]}}
> ```

However, the problem still has one more tricky pitfall lurking: The envelope ("green") appears to be the lower boundary of the projection and to be tangent at about `p1 == 0.2` to the red line, which corresponds to the boundary of the `ContourPlot` where `c0 == 0`.  In fact, the envelope passes out of the plot region into a region where `c0 < 0`, and the red line becomes the lower boundary, which can be seen by inspecting the value of `c0` at `p1 = 0.3`.

```
boundariesPlot = Plot[Evaluate[Append[p2 /. sols, fp2[p1] /. First@bdy]], {p1, 0, 0.3}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red, Darker@Green}]
```

[image: Three potential boundary lines]

```
fc0[0.3] /. First@bdy
```

> ```
> -0.488191
> ```

So we need to find where the envelope crosses `c0 == 0`:

```
tanPt = p1 /. FindRoot[fc0[p1] /. bdy, {p1, 0.2}]
```

> ```
> 0.196357
> ```

Then we can plot the projection of the region: The first solution in `sols` (where `c0 == 1`) is the upper boundary.  The lower is equal either `fp2` or the second solution in `sols` depending on `p1`; you can use `Piecewise` or an `If` statement.

```
pl = With[{fp2 = fp2 /. First@bdy},
      Plot[
       {p2 /. First@sols,
        Piecewise[
          {{fp2[p1], fp2["Domain"][[1, 1]] <= p1 <= tanPt},
           {p2 /. Last@sols, True}}]
         },
       {p1, 0, 0.3}, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}, 
       FillingStyle -> Directive[Red, Opacity[0.5]], PlotStyle -> None, 
       PlotRange -> {0.5, 1}]]
```

[image: Plot of projection]

You can make a `Polygon` of the projection from a plot, if you omit `PlotStyle -> None`.  It may be more convenient to combine it with other graphics.  Extract the two graphs with `Cases` and stitch the points together, reversing the direction of one of the lines.

```
envPts = Join[First[#], Reverse@Last[#]] &@Cases[
    With[{fp2 = fp2 /. First@bdy},
     Plot[Evaluate[
       {p2 /. First@sols,
        Piecewise[
         {{fp2[p1], fp2["Domain"][[1, 1]] <= p1 <= tanPt},
          {p2 /. Last@sols, True}}]
        }],
      {p1, 0, 0.3}]], Line[pts_] :> pts, Infinity];
envPlot = Graphics[{Opacity[0.5], Red, Polygon[envPts]},
   Axes -> True, PlotRange -> {.5, 1}, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio];

Show[envPlot, boundariesPlot]
```

[image: Comparison of projection and boundaries]

Here we can compare the easy and hard ways.  The easy way is recolored `Blue` and so differences will show up as `Blue` or light `Red`.  Close inspection shows that the easy way has greater granularity typical of surface plots.

```
Show[proj /. _RGBColor -> Blue, envPlot,
 AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, PlotRange -> {0.5, 1}]
Show[proj /. _RGBColor -> Blue, envPlot,
 AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRange -> {{0, 0.02}, {.7, 1}}]
```

[image: Comparison of projections]
[image: Close up]

While some steps might be automated, it seems that in any particular case, you're going to have to inspect what's going on and make an intelligent choice.  The "easy way" above is fairly straightforward.

### Edit 2 - 3rd way - MeshFunctions

We can use `MeshFunctions` to find the envelope.  It can be a good way to solve for a curve on a surface.

This way still has its hangups.  The graph gets extremely flat near `p1 == 0` and it's hard to compute anything.  Still, we can do well enough if we increase the precision and subdivide the plot region as we approach `p1 == 0`.  The following goes down to `p1 = 3*10^(-10)` an order of magnitude at a time.

```
Table[
   mymesh[i] = With[{prec = 200},
     ContourPlot3D[Evaluate @ eqn,
      {p1, 3*10^(-i - 1), 3*10^(-i)}, {p2, SetPrecision[0.5, prec], 1}, {c0, 0, 1},
      PlotPoints -> 50, MaxRecursion -> 3, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
      BoundaryStyle -> None,  ContourStyle -> None,
      MeshFunctions -> {Function[{p1, p2, c0},
         Evaluate[CubeRoot@D[Subtract @@ eqn, {c0}]]]}, 
      WorkingPrecision -> prec]
     ], {i, 9}]; // Timing
```

> ```
> {4.208199, Null}
> ```

The curve is still a ways from reaching `p2 == 1`, but it doesn't matter for the sake of plotting.  We are concerned with `p2` as a function of `p1`, and we don't need `p1` much below `10^-4` or `10^-5` -- we can just connect a straight line to the endpoint.  Here the segments of the envelope are colored differently:

```
With[{i1 = 1, i2 = 9}, 
 Graphics3D[
  MapThread[Cases[#1, 
     GraphicsComplex[pts_, g_, rest___] :> GraphicsComplex[pts, {#2, Thick,
        Select[Cases[g, _Line, Infinity], 
         Last @ pts[[ #[[1, 1]] ]] < 0.5 &&
           (First@pts[[ #[[1, 1]] ]] > 0.1 || Last@pts[[ #[[1, 1]] ]] > 0.001) &]
        }]] &,
   {Table[mymesh[i], {i, i1, i2}], Table[Hue[i/9], {i, i1, i2}]}],
  PlotRange -> {{0, 0.2}, {0.6, 1}, {0, 0.3}}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, 
  Axes -> True, 
  AxesLabel -> {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(p\), \(1\)]\)",
                "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(p\), \(2\)]\)", "C"}]
 ]
```

[image: Envelope on surface]

Collect the points down to `p1 == 3 * 10^-5`:

```
envelopePoints = Append[With[{i1 = 1, i2 = 4},
    Flatten[
     Map[Cases[#1, GraphicsComplex[pts_, g_, rest___] :>
         pts[[
           Select[Cases[g, _Line, Infinity], 
             Last@pts[[#[[1, 1]]]] < 0.5 &&
               (First@pts[[#[[1, 1]]]] > 0.1 ||
                  Last@pts[[#[[1, 1]]]] > 0.001) &][[1, 1]]
           ]] ] &,
      Table[mymesh[i], {i, i1, i2}]],
     2]
    ], {0., 1., 0.}];
```

Then join them with the other parts of the boundary and compare with the other methods.

```
envMeshPlot = 
 Graphics[{Opacity[0.5], Red, 
   Polygon @ Join[Table[{p1, p2 /. Last@sols}, {p1, 0.3, 0.2, -0.01}], 
     Most /@ envelopePoints, 
     Table[{p1, p2 /. First@sols} /. p1 -> p^2, {p, 0, Sqrt[0.3], Sqrt[0.3]/100}]]}]

Show[proj /. _RGBColor -> Blue, envMeshPlot,
 AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRange -> {{0, 0.005}, {.7, 1}}, Axes -> False]
Show[envMeshPlot, envPlot /. _RGBColor -> Blue,
 AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRange -> {{0, 0.005}, {.7, 1}}, Axes -> False]
```

[image: Envelope and comparisions]

The first method is easiest; the drawback is that the overlapping polygons make `Opacity` give an nonuniform appearance.

Comment: your easy way already solve my question, but I would like to see roughly what the hard way is if you could show me.

Comment: by the way, how can I add the axes and the axes labels to your 2d plot?

Comment: @wdg I responded to both comments in the updated answer.

Comment: very grateful for your in-depth answers!

Answer (score 9):

Add `ViewPoint -> {0, 0, \[Infinity]}` to your ContourPlot3D command and to get the projection onto the $p_1$ $p_2$ plane

[image]

Comment: It would be nice if you can clean up the region, because I need to plot other curves on top of that region.

Comment: What do you mean by "clean up"? If you change the options like Lighting and etc you can change the appearance. Or the Opacity you have specified makes it have the different shades.

Comment: How about Lighting->None and Opacity[0.1]?

Comment: The color of the region is still not uniform...