# Is it possible to project a 3D contour plot onto two dimensional space?

Tags: plotting, projection

I like to draw project of ContourPlot3D into "p-q" plane, but is it possible to do it with *Mathematica*?

Here is my ContourPlot3D:

```
ContourPlot3D[(a*p^2)/(2*(1 - p^2)) + 
   1/2 - (1 - a)*(q*((1 + 2*q - 2*q^2)/(q^2) + 2*p*(1 - p)/(1 - p^2) ) + 
       1)/(2*(1 + q)) == 0, {p, 0.01, 0.99}, {q, 0.01, 0.99}, {a, 0, 1}, 
   Axes -> True, 
   AxesLabel -> {"p value", "q value", "alpha value"}, 
   PlotLabel -> "Even curve"]
```

In addition, can we also put the value of alpha in the picture of the projection?

Comment: See http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26228/projection-of-contourplot3d?rq=1. Also, when giving input, please use indenting so as to create a code block.

Comment: I was about to post an answer, but I'm slightly confused by `"can we also put the value of alpha in the picture of the projection?"` What exactly do you mean? If you're projecting down to the p-q plane, that's using every alpha value. So do you mean you want to take slices parallel to the p-q plane? Or are you wanting something like [this](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/basic-and-formula-regions/formula-region-projections.html)?

Comment: Yes, when we project to p-q plane, we are using all alpha values. I am wondering if we could label a few cases such as alpha=0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7 so on. But first I like to know how to project ContourPlot3D. Thanks you in advance.

Comment: Yes, I looked at http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26228/projection-of-contourplot3d?rq=1 before I posted this question. I tried to follow the guideline, but somehow it kept having errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand your question correctly. If not I will delete this answer.

Is this what you want?

```
ContourPlot[
  Evaluate[a /. 
    Solve[(a*p^2)/(2*(1 - p^2)) + 
      1/2 - (1 - a)*(q*((1 + 2*q - 2*q^2)/(q^2) + 
      2*p*(1 - p)/(1 - p^2)) + 1)/(2*(1 + q)) == 0, a]
  ], 
  {p, 0, 1}, {q, 0, 1}, 
  FrameLabel -> {"p value", "q value"},
  PlotLegends -> Automatic
]
```

[image]

Comment: Yes!!!! Thank you very much.